# ¿Como dar dos values a input radio?

Tags: php, html

```
<form method="POST" action="" >
<label>Sexo: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="sexusu" value="M">
                <label>Masculino</label>
    
                <input type="radio" name="sexusu" value="F">
                <label>Femenino</label><br>
    
            <label>Estado Civil: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="estadociusu" value="S">
                <label>Soltero(a)</label>
    
                <input type="radio" name="estadociusu" value="C">
                <label>Casado(a)</label>   
    
                <input type="radio" name="estadociusu" value="V">
                <label>Viudo(a)</label>
    
                <input type="radio" name="estadociusu" value="D">
                <label>Divorciado(a)</label><br> 

                <input type="submit" name='guardar' value='guardar'>
</form>
    <?php
    
    if (isset($_POST["guardar"])) {

        echo $_POST["sexusu"];
        echo $_POST["estadociusu"];
    }

    ?>
```

> Como puedo hacer para que al seleccionar el sexo M o F me pueda dar un value en estado civil segun en sexo ejemplo:
> Masculino el value de estado civil debe ser Soltero;
> Femenino el value de estado civil debe ser Soltera.

Comment: Para eso no puedes usar php, pues php se ejecuta solo en servidor y el código necesitará comprobar qué marca el usuario en el cliente. Tendrás que usar javascript.

Comment: No necesariamente, el esta usando `echo` para reproducir los valores, un simple `if` podria funcionar, pero no veo que tiene de malo Soltero(a)

Comment: Eso es un a pequeña parte del codigo, lo que hace en realidad es que el formulario que se guarda una base de datos

Comment: Opino lo mismo que @alanfcm, podrías dejarlo como `Soltero(a)` etc. No veo por qué haya que complicar el código para cambiar entre la  `o` y la `a` cuando no tiene ninguna utilidad realmente...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes actualizar el texto usando el evento `onchange` en el selector de Sexo, y ajustar las etiquetas segun el valor seleccionado, aqui un ejemplo con las primeras 2 opciones, el resto sería la misma idea.

```html
<form method="POST" action="" >
<label>Sexo: </label>
  <input type="radio" name="sexusu" onchange="sexusuario(this.value)" value="M">
  <label>Masculino</label>

  <input type="radio" name="sexusu" onchange="sexusuario(this.value)" value="F">
  <label>Femenino</label><br>

<label>Estado Civil: </label>
  <input type="radio" name="estadociusu" value="S">
  <label id="soltero">Soltero(a)</label>

  <input type="radio" name="estadociusu" value="C">
  <label id="casado">Casado(a)</label>   

  <input type="radio" name="estadociusu" value="V">
  <label>Viudo(a)</label>

  <input type="radio" name="estadociusu" value="D">
  <label>Divorciado(a)</label><br> 

  <input type="submit" name='guardar' value='guardar'>
</form>
<script>
function sexusuario(value){
   if (value=="M"){
      document.getElementById("soltero").innerText="Soltero";
      document.getElementById("casado").innerText="Casado";      
   }
   if (value=="F"){
      document.getElementById("soltero").innerText="Soltera";
      document.getElementById("casado").innerText="Casada";      
   }
}
</script>
```